# Show the commutator subgroup of $S_{n}$ is $A_{n}$ for $n \geq 5$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Show that for $n \geq 5$, the commutator subgroup of $S_{n}$ is $A_{n}$ for $n \geq 5$.

---

I'm not sure on how to handle this problem. I know that the commutator subgroup $G'$ will consist of products of commutators $[\sigma_{i}, \tau_{i}]$ for permutations $\sigma_{i}, \tau_{i} \in S_{n}$. However, I don't know where to start. What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 26):

- $A_n$ is generated by elements of the type $(abc)$ (i.e. 3-cycles)
- Each $3$-cycle is a commutator: $(abc)=(ab)(ac)(ab)(ac)$.
- $[S_n:A_n]=2$.

Can you complete the proof now?

Answer (score 24):

Let us first prove the following lemma:

**Lemma:**
Let $n>2$. Then $A_{n}$ is generated by 3-cycles.

**Proof:**
The product $(1\,2)(2\, 3)$ is equal to the 3-cycle $(1\, 2\, 3)$. The product of two disjoint 2-cycles $(i\, j)$ and $(k\, l)$ is equal to $(i\, j)(j\, k)(j\, k)(k\, l)$ and is hence a product of two 3-cycles. Since any element of $A_{n}$ is a product of an even number of transpositions, it is therefore a product of 3-cycles.
$\square$

We are now ready to prove the theorem:
**Proof:**
Since $S_{n}/A_{n}$ is commutative, the commutator subgroup $S_{n}^{′}$ is contained in $A_{n}$. Conversely, we have

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (1\, 2)(1\, 3)(1\, 2)^{−1} (1\, 3)^{−1} = (1\, 2\, 3)$

showing that every 3-cycle is in $S_{n}^{′}$ . By the previous lemma, $A_{n}$ is generated by 3-cycles, so $S_{n}^{′} = A_{n}$ as required.
$\square$

**Extra:**
It is also useful to consider the identity

$\quad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad(1\,2\,3)(3\,4\,5)(1\,2\,3)^{−1}(3\,4\,5)^{−1} = (1\,4\,3)$

which shows that for $n ≥ 5$, every 3-cycle is a commutator of $A_{n}$, which implies that the commutator subgroup of $A_{n}$ is $A_{n}$ itself.

Answer (score 10):

The fact that $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$ can be used to answer this question in quite a different way from the other answers. Let $N=[S_n, S_n]$ denote the commutator subgroup. Then:

1. (General fact about groups.) Note that $G/H$ is abelian if and only if $[G, G]\leq H$.
2. $N\leq A_n$ as $S_n/A_n$ is abelian. Note that as $N$ is normal in $S_n$ it is also normal in $A_n$.
3. $N$ is non-trivial as $S_n$ is non-abelian.
4. Therefore, $N$ is a non-trivial, normal subgroup of $A_n$. As $A_n$ is simple we have that $N=A_n$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

not only for $n≥5$, $S_{n}^{'}=A_n$ holds for every positive integer $n$

we know $ker(S_n→\left\{±1\right\})＝A_n$

$S_n/A_n=\left\{[1],[-1]\right\}\cong\left\{±1\right\}$ is abelian

so for $\forall a,b\in S_n$, the product of cosets $(aA_{n})(bA_{n})＝(bA_{n})(aA_{n})$

$ab((ba)^{-1})=aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in A_n$

$S_{n}^{'}\subseteq A_n$

**1)** $\textbf{n≥5}$

$S_{n}^{'}$ is the characteristic subgroup of $S_n$

and every characteristic subgroup is normal

$A_n$ is simple group

so $S_{n}^{'}$ might only be $\left\{1\right\}$ or $A_n$

$S_n$ is non-abelian

so $S_{n}^{'}≠\left\{1\right\}$, that is, $S_{n}^{'}=A_n$

**2)** $\textbf{n＜5}$

$S_1=A_1=\left\{1\right\}$ is abelian

$S_{1}^{'}=\left\{1\right\}=A_1$

$S_2=\left\{1,(\textbf{1 2})\right\}$ is abelian

$S_{2}^{'}=\left\{1\right\}=A_2$

$S_3=\left\{1,\textbf{(1 2)},\textbf{(1 3)},\textbf{(2 3)},\textbf{(1 2 3)},\textbf{(1 3 2)}\right\}$

...

$\textbf{(1 2 3)(1 2)(1 3 2)(1 2)} = \textbf{(1 2 3)}$

...

$S_{3}^{'}=\left\{1,\textbf{(1 2 3)},\textbf{(1 3 2)}\right\}=A_3$ in which there are all even permutations

we can prove that there are only $2$ proper normal subgroups of $S_4\cong O$, octahedral group. One is $A_4$ of index $2$, the other is $H=\left\{1,\textbf{(1 2)(3 4)},\textbf{(1 3)(2 4)},\textbf{(1 4)(2 3)}\right\}\cong V=K_4$, Klein four-group, which represents the rotations of $π$ rad about 3 vertices in octahedral group $O$

$S_4$ is non-abelian

so $S_{4}^{'}≠\left\{1\right\}$

so we just need to find a $g\in S_{4}^{'}$ but $g\notin H$, so as to prove $S_{4}^{'}≠H$, moreover, $S_{4}^{'}＝A_4$

we could easily find a $g=\textbf{(1 2 3 4)(1 2 3)(1 4 3 2)(1 3 2)}=\textbf{(1 4 2)}\notin H$

in summary, $S_{n}^{'}=A_n$ holds for every positive integer $n$