# Finding a commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $C_r=\langle x\rangle$ be the cyclic group with $r$ elements (but written with multiplication, rather than addition).  Let
$W_{r,n}$ be the set of all $a\in M_n(C_r\cup\{0\})$ such that $a$ has exactly one nonzero entry in every row and every column.

Find the commutator subgroup for $W_{2,n}$

Edit: I understand that to find a commutator, I need to find elements in the form $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$.  I'm stuck on two things:
(1) what do the elements of $W_{2,n}$ look like
(2) how do a form a subgroup based off of the commutator(s) found?

Edit (2): My intuitive thinking is that it diagonal matrices with diagonal entries in $C_2$ due to their multiplicative closeness to allow for commutators to produce matrices in $W_{2,n}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I don't know how to represent this symbolically, but I am thinking that an $a\in W_{2,n}$ would be a matrix with up to n columns and rows with an entry of $C_2= \{e,x\}$ where e is the identity.  I'm just stuck on how to create commutators based off of that, and then to eventually define a commutator subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you write $C_2$ multiplicatively, you have $C_2=\{1,-1\}$. Then $n\times n$ matrices with exactly a $1$ in each row and column are the permutations. You also want to allow $-1$ instead of $1$; you can achieve that by multiplying a permutation by a diagonal matrix with the diagonal consisting of $1$ and $-1$. So
$$
W_{2,n}=\{DP:\ D\ \text{ diagonal, }D_{kk}\in\{1,-1\},\ P\ \text{ a permutation}\}.
$$
To look at commutators in $W_{2,n}$, note that $PD=D'P$ for another diagonal matrix of ones and minus ones, so you can just look at commutators of permutations and apply the signs at the end (that is, you can always keep the $D$ at the left). Note that a product of permutations is again a permutation. It is known that the commutators of the permutations are the even permutations (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669313/calculate-the-commutator-subgroup-of-s-4) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501395/show-the-commutator-subgroup-of-s-n-is-a-n-for-n-geq-5/1505560#1505560)). So 
$$
W_{2,n}'=\{DP:\ D\ \text{ diagonal, }D_{kk}\in\{1,-1\},\ P\ \text{ an even permutation}\}.
$$